# mPDF generate data only one page

Tags: php, html, laravel, mpdf

How to setting mPDF generate all data only in one page? I already create function to generate my data to pdf file like

```
$fileName = "installment_".generateUuid().".pdf";
$pdf = LARAVELPDF::loadView('invoice.invoice-wa', $this->strukData);
$pdf->save(storage_path('app/public/'.$fileName));
```

I used https://github.com/niklasravnsborg/laravel-pdf

And my code output 2 page like

[image]

Is it possible with a lot of data on one page?

Thanks

Comment: Maybe this solution? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33022101/mpdf-document-auto-height-pos-printer

Comment: tried using landscape mode?